# Servlet doesn't execute response.sendRedirect(addressPath); , but does execute response.sendRedirect() without path

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

Consider the following hierarchy :

[image]

When I send redirect like this :

```
    response.sendRedirect("error404.jsp");    // no path here !!!
```

I reach the page `error404.jsp` .

But when I use a path :

```
    String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/admin/adminPage.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(addressPath);   // with path !!!
```

I get 404 :

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

> This method can accept relative URLs;the servlet container must
>   convert the relative URL to an absolute URL before sending the
>   response to the client. **If the location is relative without a leading
>   '/' the container interprets it as relative to the current request
>   URI. If the location is relative with a leading '/' the container
>   interprets it as relative to the servlet container root.** If the
>   location is relative with two leading '/' the container interprets it
>   as a network-path reference (see RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI): Generic Syntax, section 4.2 "Relative Reference").

Note that the argument is not a path within the servlet context like a `RequestDispatcher` would use, it as a URL used in the `Location` header of the 302 response.

So this

```
String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/admin/adminPage.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(addressPath);   // with path !!!
```

will be transformed into a 302 response with the header

```
Location: http://whateverhost.com/WEB-INF/results/admin/adminPage.jsp
```

which you don't have a handler for, so 404.

On the other hand, this

```
response.sendRedirect("error404.jsp");    // no path here !!!
```

becomes

```
Location: http://whateverhost.com/context-path/error404.jsp
```

Since `error404.jsp` is outside `WEB-INF`, it is accessible and therefore rendered by the JSP servlet and returned as a response.

Answer (score 2):

Because stuff under WEB-INF is not accessible to the client. Don't put your JSPs under WEB-INF if you want them to be accessible.

Alternatively, to make anything under WEB-INF accessible to the client, you would have to map it to a URL in web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>adminPage</servlet-name> 
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/results/admin/adminPage.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>adminPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adminPage/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then use the url-pattern you mapped:

```
response.sendRedirect("./adminPage/");
```

Which is rather pointless. You could achieve basically the same thing with your JSP outside of WEB-INF and using a URL Rewrite Filter.  In short, you probably have no real reason to put your JSPs under WEB-INF.